# Compact boundary of non compact manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

As the title suggests - is there a non compact SMOOTH manifold with a compact boundary?

Please avoid examples of empty boundary.

Comment: Delete the open unit disc from the plane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure: take $[0, 1) \times \mathbb S^1$.

Comment: It's interesting to note that this example and the one given in a comment by @conditionalMethod are actually diffeomorphic to each other.